# EMR 6.3 Spark 3.1.1 resource file MalformedInputException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a maven project with a `category.txt` file in src/main/resources.

I have a simple job:

```
package com.test.utilityjobs

import scala.io.Source

object CategoriesLoadingTestJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val categoryListSource = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/categories.txt"))
    categoryListSource.getLines().toList.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Which works fine if launched on my local machine or in emr 5.*

However, in emr 6.3, whenever I launch this simple job, I get this error:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I've also tried

```
val categoryListSource: BufferedSource = Source.fromResource("cat2.txt")
```

but this gives me the same error.

I've checked the file encoding, it is UTF-8. The compiler encoding is UTF-8. I've tried with other files and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to specify the encoding while reading a property file in scala, so I tried

```
val categoryListSource = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/categories.txt"))("UTF-8")
```

and it worked. It still complains about files with BOM so I removed the BOM from the existing file.